# Zend Framework Routing Issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I have a module with the following in the `module.config.php`

```
<?php
return array(
        'controllers' => array(
                'invokables' => array(
                        'BlindQC\Controller\BlindQC' => 'BlindQC\Controller\BlindQCController',
                ),
        ),
        // The following section is new and should be added to your file
        'router' => array(
                'routes' => array(
                        'blinqc' => array(
                                'type' => 'Segment',
                                'options' => array(
                                        'route' => '/blindqc/jobs[/:user_id]',
                                        'defaults' => array(
                                                '__NAMESPACE__' => 'BlindQC\Controller',
                                                'controller' => 'BlindQC',
                                                'action' => 'index',
                                        ),
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        'view_manager' => array(
                'template_path_stack' => array(
                        'blindqc' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
                ),
        ),
);
```

This allows  me to go to `www.example.com/blindqc/jobs` or `www.example.com/blindqc/jobs/123456`

On this page I have a search box where the user can enter a `user_id`, which upon hitting `Search` should redirect them to the url followed by the entered `user_id`.  So if they type `999999` it should take them to `www.example.com/blindqc/jobs/999999`.  I seem to be having an issue using routes to get them there.

I've tried:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute("blindqc/jobs/", array("user_id" => $userId));
```

But I get an error:

> Route with name "blindqc" not found

What am I doing incorrectly? As far as I can tell the route is defined correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third line in the snippet below reads `blinqc` whereas it ought to be `blindqc`.

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'blinqc' => array(
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that -_-.  Thank you!